# Read headers and N rows of data

Tags: python, json, csv, xlsx, xls

I have a function that accepts four types of files:

- `.csv`
- `.xls`
- `.xlsx`
- `.json`

The files can contain up to a couple thousand rows of data. I want to get the column headers for the file, and `N` example rows of data (doesn't need to be the first N, but need to be a total of N). An example:

From `animals.csv`:

[image: animals.csv]

To:

```
animals = {
    "dogs": [1, 5, 8],
    "cats": [2, 6, 9],
    "birds": [3, 10, 14],
    "frogs": [4, 8, 11]
}
```

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Test files:

- [animals.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0k3kfawonjw3br5/animals.csv?dl=0)
- [animals.json](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0w5emix3nutk6oh/animals.json?dl=0)
- [animals.xls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kp8e2idee3g5nx0/animals.xls?dl=0)
- [animals.xlsx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/85c3s0qs04l2gw5/animals.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Is pandas an acceptable option for you?

Comment: My solution coming soon. Pandas is indeed acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. I don't claim for it to be the "most efficient" though. You'll need to install [xlrd](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) (`pip3 install xlrd`). The test files are available in the question description.

---

```
import collections
import pathlib
import csv
import json
import xlrd

file = "animals.csv"

f_sufx = pathlib.Path(file).suffix
if f_sufx == ".csv":
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        d = collections.defaultdict(set)
        for r in reader:
            for k, v in r.items():
                if len(d[k]) < 3 and v:
                    d[k].add(v)
elif f_sufx == ".json":
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        d = collections.defaultdict(set)
        for r in json.load(f):
            for k, v in r.items():
                if len(d[k]) < 3 and v:
                    d[k].add(v)
elif f_sufx in [".xls", ".xlsx"]:
    d = collections.defaultdict(set)
    sh = xlrd.open_workbook(file).sheet_by_index(0)  
    for row in range(2, sh.nrows):
        for col in range(sh.ncols):
            if len(d[sh.cell_value(1, col)]) < 3 and sh.cell_value(row, col):
                d[sh.cell_value(1, col)].add(sh.cell_value(row, col))

print(d)
```